# HTML list content direction in rtl

Tags: html, right-to-left

I have a simple HTML unordered list

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link1</a> <a href="#">link2</a> text1</li>
    <li>text1 <a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li>text1 text2</li>
</ul>
```

If I have normaln ltr layout, final content looks like this

*link1 link2* text1
text1 *link*
text1 text2

However, if the content inside a list item is mixed, and direction is set to rtl, I get a complete mess

*link2* text1 *link1*
text1 *link*
text2 text1

which means only the list element containing text only gets reversed properly. Any ideas on how to get this working correctly?

edit:
It seems that the content flow depends on the actual content. A simple example like this doesn't work

```
<ul dir="rtl">
  <li>
    <a href="#">12:30 - 13:30</a>
    some text
    <a href="#">link text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul dir="ltr">
  <li>
    <a href="#">12:30 - 13:30</a>
    some text
    <a href="#">link text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 26):

**It works out of the box**

The attribute `dir="RTL"`

using your markup only position the content at the right side

```html
  <div dir="RTL">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">My Web Home Site</a> <a href="#">My Other Web Site</a> My First Text</li>
      <li>My First Text <a href="#">My First Link</a></li>
      <li>My First Text, My Second text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <hr/>
  
  <div dir="LTR">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">My Web Home Site</a> <a href="#">My Other Web Site</a> My First Text</li>
      <li>My First Text <a href="#">My First Link</a></li>
      <li>My First Text, My Second text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

It's all a matter of how you **write** your content, [more information here](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html)

Answer (score 10):

you could this Html/CSS styling for Arabic Language

```
"<ol style="list-style-type:arabic-indic ;direction:RTL; text-align: right"><li>مرحبا بك و اهلا و سهلا </li></ol>"
```

Answer (score -1):

If "dir" does not work on the page, just use this:

```
style="text-align: right;
```

For a sample "li" tag:

```
<ul>
<li style="text-align: right;">
blah blah....
</li>
...
</ul>
```